# Special chars in SQL regex - match word boundary with special chars

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I've got a search function which creates query. My goal is to search for exact word, so if the phrase is 'hello' it should return only results with 'hello' (not with 'xhello', 'helloxx' etc). My code looks like:

```
SELECT (...) WHERE x RLIKE '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]'
```

And it works for most of the cases, BUT
the problem starts when the phrase is f.e. '$hello', or 'helloŁ' etc - the special chars ruin the functionality.

Is there a way to handle it ?

Comment: You may check if the word appears at the start/end of the string and if it is surrounded with spaces: `RLIKE '(^|[[:space:]])word([[:space:]]|$)'`

Comment: Wiktor - still does not work

Comment: How doesn't it "work"? See https://regex101.com/r/dX5aV9/1. It is *working*.

Comment: `$hello` does match `RLIKE '[[:<:]]hello[[:>:]]'`.  It `helloŁ` fails because `Ł` is a letter.  Please spell out all the rules you have for what a "word" is / is not.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x RLIKE '(^|[[:space:]])Hello([[:space:]]|$)'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x RLIKE '(^| )Hello( |$)'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x REGEXP '(^|[[:space:]])Hello([[:space:]]|$)'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE name REGEXP '(^| )Hello( |$)'
```

Comment: OP has already stated those ["do not work"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739216/special-chars-in-sql-regex#comment64853436_38739216).

Comment: whats the differenc between rlike and regexp ?

Comment: Both are same . Refer [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)